# Calculate the values

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate the following values:
$6-6i=z^4$
and
 $z=3i^{\pi i}$

For the first one, I have $6-6i=e^{4 \log z}$. Is that right so far or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have $z^4 $ there are 4 solutions, the log is not defined everywhere use 
$$z=|z|e^{i \varphi}$$ and find the 4 solutions.

You know that 
$$6\cdot \sqrt{2} \exp(i\frac{\pi}{4})=6(1-i)=z^4=|z|^4 \exp(4 i \varphi)$$
So you need to find solution of 
$$\frac{\pi}{4}\equiv 4 \varphi\qquad \operatorname{mod} (2\pi)$$

Comment: so the |z| would be 72^(1/2), how would i find theta?

Comment: it is a phi not a theta the angle is pi/4 so you know that 4 * phi = $\frac{\pi}{4}$ mod 2 pi

Comment: @Tom i modified my solution